# how to optimize data loading in the search area?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I have a function to display the data in the search area, the function is good, but it is slow when I want to see the data in the search area, even if we click on a data.

the data loading time is slow because I have 22500 line in the request, is there possibility to correct this, such as add a function that displays for example just 100 line.

how to fix this problem and thank's

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/i18n/fr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e9d941381475b5df8b7d7691013401e171014e89/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.0.1/spin.min.js'></script> 
.
.
.
function searchTree(obj,search,path){   
        var newSearch = search.replace(/ *\[ Resp:[^)]*\] */g, "");
        var newSearch1 = search.replace(/ *\( [^)]*\) */g, "");     
        if(obj.desc === newSearch && newSearch1){ 
            path.push(obj);
            return path;
        }
        else if(obj.children || obj._children){ 
            var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
            for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                path.push(obj);
                var found = searchTree(children[i],newSearch && newSearch1,path);
                if(found){
                    return found;
                }
                else{ path.pop();}
            }
        }
        else{ return false;}
    }
.
.
.
$("#search").on("select2:select", function(e) {     
             var data = e.params.data.text;     
        var paths = searchTree(root,data,[]);       
        if(typeof(paths) !== "undefined"){
            openPaths(paths);
        }
        else{
            alert(data+" auncun résultat!");
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the issue (a [mre]). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to have it run on this site. It would also be nice if you could tell us what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing recursive regex stuff, which sounds slow. The foundation of speeding anything up is to cache repeated work. So, take a look at why you're doing such complex regex stuff and see if you can find a way to cache things so that you don't have to do such an expensive call every time, or find a way to not do that work at all.

Like, it looks like you're running it on all child nodes in some tree. If the nodes in your tree don't change between each call, then perhaps you can preparse the nodes and put them in a data format that's more easily searchable, so that you don't have to run a recursive regex on them each time.